# Why isn't TouchListener working on custom alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, touch-event

I implmented a class that extends Dialog and implements OnTouchListener, the layout has two TextViews and a third to serve as a button, and I used the TouchListener to change the button color on ActionDown and performClick() on ActionUp but the dialog is not detecting any touch events. It used to work but then I tried to add a second button, and some methods to set the visibility and the onClick() of each button, but since that didn't work because I got an error saying that I was calling OnClickListener on a null reference I tried to revert back. But now it doesn't detect touch events.

```
public class AlertDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private TextView titleView;
    private TextView messageView;
    private TextView buttonViewLeft;


    private String title;
    private String message;
    private String textButtonLeft;
    private String textButtonRight;


    public void setTextButtonRight(String textButtonRight) {
        this.textButtonRight = textButtonRight;
    }


    public void setTextButtonLeft(String textButtonLeft) {
        this.textButtonLeft = textButtonLeft;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog);

        buttonViewLeft = findViewById(R.id.alertButton);

        buttonViewLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        titleView = findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
        messageView = findViewById(R.id.alertMessage);

        titleView.setText(title);
        messageView.setText(message);

        buttonViewLeft.setText(textButtonLeft);


    }

    public AlertDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Log.e("Touch","Touch");
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                buttonViewLeft.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.press_grey));
                buttonViewLeft.setAlpha(0.5f);

                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.performClick();
                return true;

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
 private void wrongCredentialsAlert(String e){

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.alert_incorrect_password_title) + e);
        alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_message_incorrect_password));
        alertDialog.setTextButtonLeft("OK");
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/alertBackground">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alertMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:ems="12"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/alert_message_incorrect_password"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/alertTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alertButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/separator"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/separator_grey"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/alertButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/alertMessage" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are never setting the `OnTouchListener` to anything. The `implements` only means that it has a function that has been defined in the `OnTouchListener` interface. If `onTouch` should be called you need to set it to any view with `setOnTouchListener(this)`. It seems that you want to do that with your button.

Just a side note: if you want to react to click events visually there is a bunch of possibilities with background-Drawables depending on the state in XML. The typical event you are looking for is the `OnClickListener`. Managing the visual appearance yourself in onTouch tends to create problems and I would recommend this only for specific demands.

Comment: ah right, I accidentally deleted setTouchListener. I was trying to figure this out for hours, thank you